# What overhead combos does Ryu have?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

Ryu had many changes from SSFIV to SSFIVAE and I am not sure what overhead combos work.

I found the following on some forum entry but I cannot execute it.

F + MP ~ c.LP ~ s.HP -> HP.Srk

Is this possible, how can I execute it easier (Plinking does not work for LP) and what alternatives does Ryu have?

Comment: Ultra Super Street Fighter Ultimate Tournament Turbo Style Director's Cut Limited Collector's Edition

Comment: I feel the need of a Street Fighter jargon parser to understand the question, AND the answers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess his overhead combos only works on standing characters.

Have you tried Double-Tapping?

If you link the c.LP, there are some combos that may work:

```
f+MP, c.LP, HP Shoryuken xx FADC, Ultra 1
f+MP, Super

Corner only
f+MP, c.LP xx LK Tatsu, Super
f+MP, c.LP xx EX Tatsu, Ultra 1
```

Comment: What is the purpose of an overhead combo if it works only on standing opponents? Anyway, thanks.